# When I run my query in Snowflake it keeps running but without the OR statement is runs in merely seconds

Tags: sql, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like

I have a query where I select 3 columns from two tables. First I check if a clientnumber is in the list, for which I used a "IN" statement. Then I check if a clientnumber is also in another table so that both numbers are equal.

At last I want to exclude values that are ending on a certain value. And this is where it goes wrong.

When I have just a single "NOT LIKE" it runs perfectly fine but when I use a "OR NOT LIKE" after that it keeps on running.

See my query below:

```
SELECT "MAIL_ADDR", "ClientNumber", "CNumber" 
FROM "ADRESSES", CUSTOMERS
WHERE "ClientNumber" IN ('0000206302','0000206307','0000206309','0000206321'                                        
    AND "ClientNumber" = "CNumber"
    AND "MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.nl' 
    OR "MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.com'
```

I don't know what to change in my query as I don't get any error messages from Snowflake. Maybe it has something to do with performance issues.

Comment: You don't want to use `OR` here or it will pass through every record. Instead you want `AND`. This feels counterintuitive because in English we would use `OR` to separate two negations like `At the store I don't want milk or eggs`, but in logic you need an AND: `"MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.nl'  AND "MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.com'` Likely the long run time isn't execution time, rather it's trying to return every record in a large result set.

Comment: Also, switch to a proper JOIN. Using a comma to separate your tables in your FROM clause is antiquated since `JOIN` was introduced back in the early 90s. `FROM "Adresses" INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON "ADRESSES"."ClientNumber" = CUSTOMERS."CNumber"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could be rewritten to use JOIN syntax and condition for exclusion should be connected with `AND`:

```
SELECT "MAIL_ADDR", "ClientNumber", "CNumber" 
FROM "ADRESSES"
JOIN CUSTOMERS
  ON "ClientNumber" = "CNumber"
WHERE "ClientNumber" IN ('0000206302','0000206307','0000206309','0000206321')
    AND "MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.nl' 
    AND "MAIL_ADDR" NOT LIKE '%domain.com';
```

A more compact way is to use [NOT LIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html) syntax:

```
SELECT "MAIL_ADDR", "ClientNumber", "CNumber" 
FROM "ADRESSES"
JOIN CUSTOMERS
  ON "ClientNumber" = "CNumber"
WHERE "ClientNumber" IN ('0000206302','0000206307','0000206309','0000206321')       
 AND NOT ("MAIL_ADDR" LIKE ANY ('%domain.nl', '%domain.com'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for the feedback, was a long time since I used SQL so this was an eye opener! :) Thanks guys.

Comment: Pushing the ClientNumber predicate into the join may result in a speed increase, because you're removing rows prior to the join (the joins are more expensive).